# Pygame keys convention

Tags: python, pygame

I want to use w a s d keys for movement rather than arrows key
But I can't figure out how to do so with the following piece of code. I want to replace `pygame.KEYDOWN`
with a button for s but I can't figure out how to do so.

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        Pacman.changespeed(-30, 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        Pacman.changespeed(30, 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        Pacman.changespeed(0, -30)
    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        Pacman.changespeed(0, 30)
```

Comment: I suggest using `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` inside the main loop and then accessing the keys like this: `if keys[pygame.K_yourkey]: do_stuff()` where yourkey can be any key on keyboard for example `w` or `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the event type. <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> are represented by `pygame.K_w`, `pygame.K_a`, `pygame.K_s` and `pygame.K_d`, respectively, but the event type is still `pygame.KEYDOWN`:

```py
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        Pacman.changespeed(-30, 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
        Pacman.changespeed(30, 0)
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        Pacman.changespeed(0, -30)
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
        Pacman.changespeed(0, 30)
```

Note: `KEYDOWN` does not mean the "down" key, but that a key is pressed down. The `KEYDOWN`event occurs when a key is pressed and the `KEYUP` event occurs when a key is released. See [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) and [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).